# Jailed PHP-FPM settings for TLS and DNS Resolution

Tags: php, ssl

I'm setting up a **Jailed** php website that has subfolders in the root with additional scripts.  The files in the subfolders make curl requests to external services that require **https**.

I've configured the pool configuration with `php_admin_value[curl.cainfo] = etc/ssl/cert.pem` and copied the needed resources to `etc`, `usr` paths within the **Jailed** folder.

Scripts that are in the root folder are able to run correctly however anything that is not in the root throws an `Warning: failed loading cafile stream:` etc/ssl/cert.pem'` error.

Can a fpm pool be setup to reference the needed files in the root folder regardless of where the php file is located in the folder path?

Current site structure:

```
/var/www/html 
 - php files
 - etc/resolv.conf
 - etc/ssl/
 - usr/bin/
 - folder
   -- php file
```

Comment: IF the PHP lives inside a Jailed folder - there is no way to get out of the Jail. That's the purpose of Jails, right?

Comment: I might not have been clear.  I've put the required files for the DNS resolution and certificate validation in the jailed folder and that works for php scripts at the root of the jailed folder.  However any child folder doesn't seem to know where the etc and usr folders that are relative to the child folder are.

Comment: Well, then simply put a leading slash in front of `/etc` to denote that the file/folder is at the root level and not inside the current folder.